# Mapping to "bh" causes cursor to be trapped in first column

Tags: key-bindings, cursor-movement

I'm looking to map `Ctrl-N` to `lbvhe` in normal mode. This should visually select the word under the cursor, and works fine unless the word is at the beginning of a line.

Having investigated, I've found that – in a mapping – firing `h` when the cursor is in column 1 (which should simply do nothing) "traps" the cursor at the beginning of the line. Any following movement commands seem to be ignored; `j`, `k`, `l`, `e`, and `w` all do nothing.

My mapping works perfectly on any word preceded by whitespace or punctuation, but not words preceded by the previous line's EOL.

Comment: `:h motion.txt` will blow your mind.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `viw` to visually select the current word. `iw` is a text object for the "inner" word.

I suggest you run `vimtutor` from the command line as well as look at `:h quickref` for more motions and text objects.

Comment: `viw` is the sequence I was looking for; thank-you.

Answer (score 2):

From `:h map-error` :

```
                                                            *map-error* 
Note that when an error is encountered (that causes an error message or beep)  
the rest of the mapping is not executed.  This is Vi-compatible.
```

so when you hit `h` while on the first column (or `l` on the last one) the mapping fails.

---

As @peterrincker said you could use `viw`, which has *almost* the same effect as your command (if you're not on a word `viw` will not select anything while your command will select the previous word).

---

If you still want to use your mapping you could use:

```
:nnoremap <C-n> :silent! normal! lbvhe^M
```

(`^M` being one character, use `<C-v><CR>` to enter it).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of why the mapping fails. `viw` is indeed what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @Peter's answer I think you should read [`:h text-objects`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#text-objects) because it is a really powerful Vim's feature.

Peter already mentionned `iw` which selects a word and is pretty close to what you was trying to do. It is worth mentionning `aw` which allows to select a word + a leading or trailing space (that can be useful to change the place of a word in a sentence without leaving two whitespaces instead of only one).

There is also two other texts objects pretty similar: `iW` and `aW` which selects WORDS instead of words (see [`:h WORD`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#WORD) to clarify the difference).

Finally note that text-objects can be used with all the basics commands not only `v`: `diw` will delete your word, `caW` will delete your WORD and a trailing space and switch to insert mode, `yaw` will yank the word and a trailing space, etc...